# Use cut in shell to extract last word

Tags: linux, shell, cut

I am using Red Hat linux.

I have a file `foo.txt` which reads

```
Hello world I am foo
```

I want to get the last word which is *foo* when I do `cat`

I tried seeing a few posts here which explained to use cut command but its very confusing.
Can somebody help me getting this right?

I am looking for a command which migh go something like below

```
cat foo.txt | cut <the options to get the last word /or last 3 characters>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`cut` can't count from the right. But you can use `rev` to reverse each line, than count from the left normally, and revert the line back. It's still surprisingly fast.

```
rev foo.txt | cut -d' ' -f1 | rev
```

- `-d` specifies the delimiter, I guess you want spaces when counting words
- `-f` specifies which field(s) to extract. Use `-c` to extract individual characters.

Comment: what does -f1 do?

Comment: Extracts the first field.

Answer (score 2):

As @choroba mentioned, cut can't do that.

A simple way to that is to use `awk`.

```
cat foo.txt | awk '{print $(NF)}'
```

`NF` is the `number of fields in the current record.` So the `$(NF)` would be the last word.

Comment: awk can read files, so don't even need `cat`.

Answer (score 0):

with -n [number of lines] you can limit number of lines.
use -c to limit count of characters

Answer (score 0):

If using `cat` is necessary, you can try this:

```
cat foo.txt | rev | cut -d ' ' -f 1 | rev
```

**Explanation:**
`cat` will pipe contents of `foo.txt` file to the `rev` command.
So, `rev` will receive:

```
Hello world I am foo
```

and will invert it:

```
oof ma I dlrow olleH
```

Then `cut` eill extract the first word of inverted string:

```
oof
```

Here `-d ' '` means that space character is delimiter used to split your string by several fields, and `-f 1` means you are taking the first field.

Finally, `rev` is used once again to invert extracted word again, so yo will get:

```
foo
```

Answer (score 0):

GNU grep using a PCRE to get the characters following the last whitespace in the line (or following the start of line if there is no whitespace):

```sh
grep -oP '(.*\s|^)\K.+' file
```